# Factory reset will delete admin account?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, administrator

I lost the admin account on my Mac and I want to factory reset my macbook. Will it erase all the accounts and help me create a new admin account?

Comment: There’s really no such thing as a factory reset on a Mac. You can reinstall the OS and not overwrite your existing data, or you could erase your drive and remove everything. What exactly is your goal here?  Which MacBook?  What version of macOS?

Comment: @Allan - it gets more like an iPhone every year, now has "Erase All Content and Settings." - https://support.apple.com/HT212749 Whether it will let you do that without an admin account is something I have no means of testing.

Comment: Symantecs aside, we still don’t know what issue the OP wants to solve or what the environment is

Comment: You mean "lost the password"? There are other solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

As by its name, Factory Reset will reset your device to its state as if it comes out of the factory, and therefore remove ***all*** data on it (including accounts) and install the latest available software update.

At reboot, you will be able to configure the Mac as if you got it for the first time (first use).

From [Factory Reset - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_reset):

> Computer factory resets will restore the computer to the computer's original operating system and **delete all of the user data** stored on the computer. Microsoft's Windows 8 and Windows 10, and Apple's macOS have options for this.

<sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup>

And from [How to erase all content and settings - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/personal-safety/ips4603248a8/web):

> A factory restore erases the *information and settingsm on your device.

<sup>*(Italics mine)*</sup>